# How to stop Windows Forms label text from rearranging itself

Tags: winforms

Today I tried using Windows Forms for the first time, which went pretty smoothly until I tried setting the text of a label to "0 lines", which was displayed as "lines 0" in the actual program. I tried a couple of other inputs for the Text property, and it seems the leading number in the label is always moved to the back. I couldn't find any property in the label describing some sort of numerical formatting, so I was wondering were this rearranging came from and what I could do to disable it. Thanks in advance!

[screenshot of the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJlWU.png)

[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WacUf.png)

Comment: You probably scrolled over the RightToLeft property.

Answer (score 0):

As [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) said in their comment, I simply had to change the RightToLeft property.